# Does Visual Studio 2010 create SQL Server Express, SQL Server Compact or LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studi0 2010, when I click 'Add New Item' and choose 'SQL Server Database', is it creating a SQL Server Express DB, SQL Server Compact DB or a LocalDB?

[image: Add New Item]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Express

..............................................